# Is it possible to create custom video source for HTML5 video?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video, iot

I'd like to create a custom video source object for my HTML5 video. In more details, here's what I want to do :

1. Have an HTTP Server running on an embedded iot device that is able to send array of bytes representing an image.
2. Embedded this custom video source into the "video" tag as the video source.
3. Be able to use "start/stop/pause" features like any video but have my custom source handle the underlying HTTP requests.

Is there any "easy" way to achieve this ?

My idea was to create a custom Javascript object that I would pass to the video element as the video source Object that would handle those actions.

I'd like to have some suggestions.

Thanks,

Comment: `Is there any "easy" way to achieve this ?`   I very much doubt it, Video encoding / decoding is very complex.  But maybe another idea is send the bytes and draw the video yourself using the canvas element.  You could even implement some rudimentary compression like RLE.. etc.

Comment: Alright, I see. Then would the WebSocket or WebRTC be the way to go. I need to be able to "stream" images at a reasonable frame rate ( ideally 30 fps) over a LAN. (Images are mono 8bpp 640x480). Would WebSocket or WebRTC be the way to go instead ? (sorry for the delay of response --> holidays)